# galaxy s4 Chrome mobile internet vs wifi

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile, responsive-design

the weirdest thing happened to me,
I developed responsive html document front end,
when I open it while connecting to the mobile network, the css was broken,
when I open it while connected to the wifi, it works as it should be.

the device is galaxy S4 on chrome browser.

I tried to uninstall the updates it didn't worked, I reinstall the updates it and now it works some times,

this test site is working on almost every device - including galaxy mini S4,

does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Without any other information to base an explanation on, the only thing that seems likely to cause this sort of issue is something old and incorrect being cached on one connection which was then freshly downloaded by the other connection. If you go into the settings for your browser and clear your cache, I would expect that your issue will disappear, as the type (mobile network vs. wifi) of the internet connection over which a page is loaded has no effect on the way the CSS is rendered once the browser receives it.

Comment: I did clear the cache several times, but it didn't affect anything,
also, I opened it in the incognito window and got the same thing,
I stress to you that the default browser in galaxy works just fine both ways (wifi and 3G), but in chrome it's just don't work this way.